# Get all records for an active record relationship with a where clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

A **user** has many **posts**. A **post** has many **sections**.

I want to check if a **user** has any **posts** with **sections** titled "Hello World".

What is the correct way to do this in Rails 4?

What I tried: `sections = @user.sections.where(title: "Hello World")`

Error: `NoMethodError: undefined method 'sections' for #<User::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007f8781fa9a19>`

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it this way, using the [`exists?`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods/exists%3F) method to check if any records exist with a single SQL call (without unnecessary object instantiation as with `any?` or `present?`):

```
@user.posts.includes(:sections).where(sections: {title: "Hello World"}).exists?
```

Comment: So that will return the active record association, how can I tell whether records were found? Do I have to do `.count > 0` or is there another method? I thought you could do something like `.contains?` but can't find docs on it

Comment: Just add `exists?` at the end.

Comment: Thanks @AlexeyShein and yes Donny P you can use `.exists?` at the end to check if records are present or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using :joins:

```
@user.posts.joins(:sections).where(sections: {title: "Hello World"}).any?
```

Here will be used INNER JOIN and this generates sql-query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "posts" 
INNER JOIN "sections" ON "sections"."post_id" = "posts"."id" 
WHERE "posts"."user_id" = $1 AND "sections"."title" = "Hello World"
```

Comment: Using `exists?` should be a bit more performant than `any?`, since it woun't trigger a `COUNT(*)` function, rather a simple `SELECT 1`